# how to add a new element to a 2 component array for UIPickerview in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, uipickerview

When I try and add the newItem with .count nothing shows up.  when I use it replaces  "car" and I don't see it in pickerview and also I need to scroll up and down a few times before the newItem shows up.

```
var picker1 = String()
var picker2 = String()

var pickerViewArray = [["Items", "car"], ["Action", "Turn", "Hit", "Pull", "Scrape"]]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return pickerViewArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerViewArray[component].count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerViewArray[component][row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    picker1 = pickerViewArray[0] [pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] + ""
    picker2 = pickerViewArray[1] [pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] + ""
}

func addItemsToArray () {
    stringWall = "Wall"        
    addItemAtIndex = pickerViewArray[0].count
    pickerViewArray[0].insert(newItem, at: addItemAtIndex)
    allRoomArray[arraySelector][wallButton] = stringWall

    pickingRooms()
    print(newItem)
}
```

Comment: I don't think ppl do what you want in this way. Usually, I will create a `UITableView` with customized `UITableViewCell` to fulfill dynamic list. `UIPickerView` is quite predefined and not so much dynamic view.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  The best advice you gave was that it was not meant to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ppl do what you want in this way. Usually, I will create a `UITableView` with customized `UITableViewCell` to fulfill dynamic list. `UIPickerView` is quite predefined and not so much dynamic view.

While for your code, if you really need your `UIPickerView` be dynamic so badly, I will say

> Add `self.pickerView.setNeedsLayout()` after you change your datasource, `pickerViewArray` for your case.

I tested it on XCode9 beta3, target on iOS 8.0, with Swift 3.